# For given $f(x)$ find the value of $\frac{f(101)}{f'(101)}$?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

If $$f(x)=\prod_{n=1}^{100} (x-n)^{n(101-n)}$$, then what will be the value of $$\frac{f(101)}{f'(101)}?$$

$(A)$ $5050$

$(A)$ $1/5050$

$(A)$ $10010$

$(A)$ $1/10010$

Could someone give me slight hint for this question as I am not able to initiate?

Comment: Hint: $f'(x)/f(x)$ is the derivative of $\log|f(x)|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using [logarithmic differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_differentiation#General_case):
$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\sum_{n=1}^{100} \frac{n(101-n)}{(x-n)}.$$
Hence
$$\frac{f'(101)}{f(101)}=\sum_{n=1}^{100} \frac{n(101-n)}{(101-n)}=
\sum_{n=1}^{100}n=\frac{100\cdot 101}{2}=5050.$$
So the correct answer is $1/5050$.

Answer (score 0):

The thing that they want you to evaluate is related to the logarithmic derivative, from complex analysis.

The hint is to check and use the fact that the logarithmic derivative behaves like the logarithm in the following sense:

$$\frac{(gh)'}{gh} = \frac{g'}{g} + \frac{h'}{h}.$$